# Multiple Docker containers with Avahi daemons

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bonjour, avahi

I'm trying to set up a smart-home Raspberry Pi using Docker to isolate every element of the system. However, two of those Dockers use Avahi to broadcast themselves in the home network - one contains Homebridge, the other Shairport-Sync.

After a lot of struggle I've managed to make Avahi work on one of the following: host OS, Homebridge container OR (actually, xor) Shairport container. However, when more than one daemon is running, only one of them works (the first one launched). The others just loop endlessly with "host name conflict, retrying with HOSTNAME-n", with n approaching infinity.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: It probably helps.
https://github.com/lxc/lxc/issues/25

Comment: Answered on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1280603/multiple-docker-containers-with-avahi-daemons